# Distributing an interactive matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, software-distribution

I have a Python script that generates an interactive matplotlib plot with several sliders and radio buttons using the matplotlib.widgets submodule. I'd like to let others play with the resulting plot without having to install python, scipy, numpy, and matplotlib.

I first tried converting my python script to a stand-alone executable that I could distribute. This turned out to be a nightmare - every package I tried (pyinstaller, py2exe, cx_Freeze) failed for one reason or another. The main issue I had was with integrating various scipy and matplotlib libraries, and I'm now very pessimistic about successfully "freezing" my interactive plot.

My next idea was to see if I could get some interactivity through a web browser. Using an IPython notebook with the third-party package JSAnimation initially seemed very promising (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jakevdp/JSAnimation/blob/master/animation_example.ipynb), but it seems that the package only supports the matplotlib "animate" function. This doesn't quite fit the bill for what I'd like to do, as I have multiple sliders which 1) doesn't seem to be supported by this package, and 2) even if supported, would likely result in too many static figures to pre-render effectively, since any such arrangement would require snapshots for every possible combination of the three variables.

Any ideas for how to get this interactive matplotlib plot to others without requiring them to install Python?

Comment: The easiest thing is to get them to install python.  The bundled distributions (continium anaconda or enthought canopy) give you mor-or-less single-click installs on most platforms.

Comment: also, all of numpy, matplotlib, and scipy rely on compiled extensions (c, c++, {c, c++, fortran} respectively).  Distributing built binaries for those extensions is difficult, which is why the binary installers exist (they have done all the hard work for you).